# VM Snapshot and SQL Server AG

Tags: sql-server, snapshot, google-cloud-platform

I have a SQL Server Always On with two nodes.
We recently started taking snapshots of the disks, but only on one of the nodes. To ensure that the snapshots are restorable, we decided to perform a restore test. The test machine - on a network completely isolated from the production environment - went up and the SQL itself also started successfully, but the databases did not. In the errorlog, the message says:

Skipping the default startup of database '<database_name>' because the database belongs to an availability group (Group ID: 65537). The database will be started by the availability group. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.

I tried to drop the AG but no success.
I tried to disable the checkbox at Configuration Manager but no success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such volume replication and backup solutions are supported for the servers and SQL instances, but not for the AG replication topology as a whole.

You should plan on dropping AG and the secondary replicas and rebuilding the AG after recovery of the node hosting the primary replica.

It might come up and look healthy in testing, but there's no guarantee that the replicas will be restored at the right points in time, and so you can't plan on it.

This also goes for Mirroring, Transactional Replication, etc, and is documented here:

> If multiple SQL VMs are tightly coupled with one another, individual
> VMs can fail over to the disaster recovery (DR) site but SQL high
> availability (HA) features inside the VM need to be removed and
> reconfigured after VM failover. For this reason, the following SQL
> Server features are not supported on Hyper-VM Replica:
>
> - Availability Groups
> - Database mirroring
> - Failover Cluster instances
> - Log shipping
> - Replication

[Support policy for Microsoft SQL Server products that are running in a hardware virtualization environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/support-policy-hardware-virtualization-product)